# Accessing Spotify User Data

Tags: python, oauth, spotipy

I have been reading through the docs trying to understand how I can see recently played tracks for other users. After reading the Authentication flow docs, I am still unclear on the general way to achieve this.

I have my client key and client secret. I understand I need the users to grant me access under the `user-read-recently-played` scope. My question is, how exactly does a user give me this permission and how do I access the user data from within the app?

Since there is no way to look up user ID's, does the OAuth module just keep track of which users have granted me authorization?

Comment: You generate a sign in link using the client_key and client_secret which the user is redirected to. They then sign in to Spotify and approve the relevant scopes you are requesting access to of theirs.  Once they have done that the user is redirected to a callback URL owned by you which shares an authorization code which you then use to get both a refresh and access token unique to the user.  The users access token allows you access to query the necessary API, the refresh token is used to get a new access token as they are short lived.  It's called an OAuth2 dance.

Comment: just to be clear, the callback URL shares an auth code means it passes the code back to the system (as opposed to showing one on the screen)? all the user needs to do is click the link and login to enable access?